# Is a field the smallest vector space over itself?

Tags: vector-spaces

1) A field is a vector space over itself.
2) So is a field the smallest vector space over itself?

Comment: It's  1-diml, so yes, except for the trivial vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the zero vector space $\{0\}$ is a vector space over any field.

If a vector space $V$ over a field $K$ is non-zero; i.e., it contains some $x\ne 0$, then there is a natural (i.e., linear) inclusion $K\hookrightarrow V$ given by $\lambda\mapsto\lambda x$.  So, in that sense, $K$ is the smallest non-zero $K$-vector space.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: $k$ is the minimal *nontrivial* vector space over itself. In fact, if $k$ is a field, and $V$ is a nontrivial $k$-vector space, then for any (EDIT: nonzero) vector $v\in V$ we get a set $$k_v=\{a\cdot v: a\in k\}$$ of scalar multiples of $v$. This is isomorphic to $k$ as a $k$-vector space via the map sending $a$ to $a\cdot v$; clearly the map $a\mapsto a\cdot v$ is a bijection between $k$ and $k_v$, and it's a good exercise to check that it's a linear map of $k$-vector spaces.

Comment: If $v=0$, then $a\mapsto av$ is not an injection.

Comment: @JohnGowers Derp! Quite right, fixed. (And also fixed the omission of the trivial vector space.)